# Defining a function for different samples with statistics in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm relatively new to Python and looking for some insight.

I'm trying to calculate some statistics (mean, variance and standard error) for a given number of samples. In the list `samples` I have 6 experiments with N samples. I'm using the  `numpy`  library for statistics so I'm aware of `np.mean() np.std() np.var()`

I can code something like

`print("For n =", n_rep, np.mean(res), np.std(res),np.var(res))`

Where n_rep is the number of N samples and res = some function defined earlier in the code

But it is tedious to code that for every sample, plus i dont know how to save for every experiment, so I always end up with just one set of statistics for an experiment

I would like to code something like this:

`samples = [5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 1000]
for i in samples:`

And the output should be something like this
`print("For n =", n_rep, np.mean(res), np.std(res),np.var(res))`
but a list where i get the 6 experiments

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of printing it, append the values to a list in the loop then access the list after all values have been appended

Comment: Thank you! dont know how to upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list and then append the result to it, instead of printing it.

```
import numpy as np 

samples = [5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 1000]
empty_list = []

for i in samples:
    sample_list = [i, np.mean(i), np.std(i),np.var(i)]
    empty_list.append(sample_list)
    print("For n =",sample_list)
```

Comment: And if i desire to print those statistics how could i procede?

Comment: it depends on the way you insert the data in ```empty_list``` i will update the answer with a better explaining

Comment: Hey again, thanks for the code but I've tried to crack it out for my self and cant get it right. I'll update in a comment below

Answer (score 0):

So the function I was talking about is the next one. The idea is to simulate an album filling with different sizes of samples, that is n_rep.

```
def repetitions(n_rep, stickers_total, stickers_pack):
    stickers_album = []
    while len(stickers_album) != n_rep:
        n_packs = how_many_packs(stickers_total, stickers_pack)
        stickers_album.append(n_packs)
    return stickers_album
```

n_rep IS the number of samples so for the first experiment I have 5 measures, for the second 10 and so on

When I run your code, my terminal looks like this:

```
[[5, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187], 
[20, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187], 
[50, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187], 
[100, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187], 
[200, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187], 
[1000, 866.4, 80.99283918964687, 36.22109882375187]]
```

I think since I've already defined n_rep, that's why i get the same statistics.
Any idea how to bypass it given the above function?